# vba if a condition in cells is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Have been racking my brains to solve a problem I am facing in Excel. Am very new here.

In cell `I2`  I have a value. This value changes every day depending on some conditions. Lets assume the value for today is `-1500`

In column `L` in cell `L7` to `L186` I have formulas that constantly calculate numbers based on other cells that are updating  every minute with data from an external data source

I want that the values in  `L7` to `L186`  should never exceed the value in cell `I2` which in this case is `-1500`.

Therefore if the value  in any cell in the range `L7` to `L186` breaches the value in cell  `I2` any time duning the day  I want the formula in that cell to be replaced by the existing value in `I2`.

In other words I want the calculation in that cell to stop and be replced by the value in `I2`

If statements can solve this but the only problem is that since the values are updating dynamicaly they could come back down again under `-1500` and then that number will show in that cell and I dont want that to happen,

The formula is an if statement `=IFS(I10="","",I10="long",(F10-E10)*K10,I10="short",(E10-F10)*K10)`

Can any one help me please

Comment: It seems like the min-formula would solve this for you

Comment: How are the formulas in L7:L186 written? Can't you add the condition that if it exceeds I2, then show I2?

Comment: The formula is an if statement.......=IFS(I10="","",I10="long",(F10-E10)*K10,I10="short",(E10-F10)*K10)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `=MIN($I$2, IFS(I10="","",I10="long",(F10-E10)*K10,I10="short",(E10-F10)*K10))` and the value of the formula will not be higher than the value in `I2` becaues you always take the lower value (`MIN`) of those 2.

So for example if the result of your formula `IFS(I10="","",I10="long",(F10-E10)*K10,I10="short",(E10-F10)*K10)` is `-1600` then `MIN(-1500, -1600)` will return `-1600` because it is the smaller of both values.

Comment: Thanks for your response...... My statement "I want that the values in L7 to L186 should never exceed the value in cell I2 which in this case is -1500" appears to have created some confusion. What I meant was once the value hits -1500 it should stay at -1500 and should not go either above or below this value. It should just freeze there. And hence if someone can suggest a vba code where the formula just converts itself into the value in Cell I2. My thought is that Min or Max may not work as the cells are dynamically changing on a minute by minute basis

Comment: @DigantBhansali Well then you need to show what you have tried so far because this is no free code writing service ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). What you need to do is to have this check in the code that changes your data on a minute basis. Please do some research and try something on your own. Then post your attempt in your question and ask something to it.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("f18").Value < Range("g15").Value Then


Range("f18").Formula = Range("g15").Value
End If

Comment: this is where I have managed to reach.......have got this to work for a single cell "F18".....want this to work for "f18:f40 , while keeping g15 constant....what I am not able to figure is how to apply the code for a all cells in range f18:f40........can anyone suggest how this can be done...I went through "no attempt was made" and I truly apologise for not letting member here know what I had attempted already

Comment: @DigantBhansali Please note that everything that is needed to understand your question (code etc) should be in the question itself (you can edit it and add information at any time). • Also note that `Worksheet_Change` only gets triggered on a change of a cell if content of the cell changes. It does not trigger if formula values change (there is no such event). Check the `Worksheet_Calculate` event that runs when ever any cell gets calculated. But note that this event has no `Target` so you have to loop through all cells you want to check (on **every** calculation). That is the only way you got